# I switched my shell to fish and my flutter command is broken. How do I fix this?

Tags: flutter, fish

I just recent switched my shell to `[fish][1]` and my `flutter` command doesn't seem to work anymore. the one error it returns with is

```
fish: Unknown command: flutter
```

I know I have to update my fish config but I'm not sure how to entirely fix the flutter error specifically. Could anyone help?

Comment: With recent fish versions, use [`fish_add_path`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html) command to manipulate the PATH. For older fish versions, use the [`fish_user_paths`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#special-variables) _variable_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update $PATH environment variable by adding following line to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set PATH /your/path/flutter/bin $PATH
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it didn't seem to work. I went to `/Volumes/Storage` and didn't see a flutter directory

Comment: I updated my answer. That is actually your flutter path. You can simply drag flutter folder after typing PATH to the terminal, if you couldn't do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In fish, $PATH is a list. And lists expand like brace expansions, in a
cartesian product.

That means `PATH=$PATH:something` will expand to `PATH=$PATH[1]:something PATH=$PATH[2]:something` and so on.

```
set PATH $PATH /Users/{username}/flutter/bin
```

This command append Flutter binaries to PATH and the problem should be gone.